# Meaning of 'this' in case of struct and class

Tags: c#

In msdn article:

> Within an instance constructor or instance function member of a class,
>   this is classified as a value. Thus, while this can be used to refer
>   to the instance for which the function member was invoked, it is not
>   possible to assign to this in a function member of a class. Within an
>   instance constructor of a struct, this corresponds to an out parameter
>   of the struct type, and within an instance function member of a
>   struct, this corresponds to a ref parameter of the struct type. In
>   both cases, this is classified as a variable, and it is possible to
>   modify the entire struct for which the function member was invoked by
>   assigning to this or by passing this as a ref or out parameter.

Can you provide me an example for struct and class that shows this.

Comment: Not a single "object oriented programming tutorial" result on Google gave an answer you liked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a class, the `this` keyword refers to the current instance of a class, or the instance that a particular method was invoked on.
You can also use the `this` keyword in a struct and it will refer to the current instance of the struct.

**Usage in Struct:**

In the example below, the `this` keyword is used to refer to the fields of the current instance of the struct, to distinguish them from the input parameters that have the same name.

```
public struct BoxSize
{
    public double x;
    public double y;
    public double z;

    public bool HasBiggerVolume(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        if ((this.x * this.y * this.z) > (x * y * z))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

**Usage in Class:**

```
class student
{  
    int id;  
    String name;  

    student(int id,String name)
    {  
        id = id;  
        name = name;  
    }  
    void display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(id+" "+name);
    }  
    public static void main()
    {  
        student s1 = new student(1,"NameA");  
        student s2 = new student(2,"NameB");  
        s1.display();  
        s2.display();  
    }  
}
```

Output will be:

```
0 null
0 null
```

Solution for the problem:

```
class Student
{  
    int id;  
    String name;  
    student(int id,String name)
    {  
        this.id = id;  
        this.name = name;  
    }  
    void display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(id+" "+name);
    }  
    public static void main()
    {  
        Student s1 = new Student(1,"NameA");  
        Student s2 = new Student(2,"NameB");  
        s1.display();  
        s2.display();  
    }  
}
```

Output will be:

```
1 NameA
2 NameB
```

FYI, here is given the 6 usage of `this` keyword.

1. `this` keyword can be used to refer current class instance variable.
2. `this()` can be used to invoke current class constructor.
3. `this` keyword can be used to invoke current class method (implicitly)
4. `this` can be passed as an argument in the method call.
5. `this` can be passed as argument in the constructor call.
6. `this` keyword can also be used to return the current class instance.

Comment: Isnt this the same way we do it for a class also?

Comment: That looks like java - question is tagged c#! ;)

Comment: @NachiketKamat: Edited my answer. Included for both class and struct.

Comment: @variable: Did my answer get you what you are looking for?